# switch template url basis of number of stateparameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i am trying to load the template according to the parameters pass in the route.

eg.

```
.state('menue.courses-detail',{
                   url:'/courses/:id',
                   templateUrl:'templates/courses.html'

            })
```

now in this case for url `"#courses/1"` its loading my courses template.
now how may i proceed when i need to proceed with its child url.
eg with

```
"courses/1/1" or "courses/1/2" ...
```

is called in url then i need to load `lectures.html`

This how i tried to

```
.state('menue.courses-detail.lectures-detail',{
                   url:'/courses/:id/:lid',
                   templateUrl:'templates/lectures-detail.html'

            })
```

but its not working

Comment: make another child state? .state('menue.courses-detail.lectures') ? and pass in another url /courses/:id/:id

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion ,you could call `init` method inside that controller make an one more AJAX call and initialized  child url .

Comment: can you please give me snippet to explain your answer?

Comment: ok I will  also could please tell me when will u want the child's url state like the user may clik the button etc..

Comment: How do you call your child's url ? LIke while the user may trigger any buttn or at the first time controller initialization  the child url call or how ? If you tell it will be useful to us...